# Jade - Trying display collection data from mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

i want to display data from mongodb collection

i am using pug for and want to display my data collection in mongodb

but i have no idea, about this error

i have tried this

it's my .pug file

```
extends layout

block content
    if registrations.length
        table
            tr
                th Name
                th Email
            each registration in registrations
                tr
                    td=registration.name
                    td=registration.email
    else
        p No registrations yet
```

it's my index.js file

```
const Registration = mongoose.model('Registration');
router.get('/registrations', (req, res) => {
    Registration.find()
        .then((registrations) => {
            res.render('index', { title: 'Listing registrations' });
        })
        .catch(() => { res.send('Something went wrong'); });
});
```

it's the error message

```
TypeError: E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\views\index.pug:4
    2| 

    3| block content

  > 4|     if registrations.length

    5|         table

    6|             tr

    7|                 th Name


Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:21:19)
    at template (eval at wrap (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:79:50)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:427:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:417:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:464:11)
    at View.render (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at Registration.find.then (E:\web_apps_project\demo-node-app\routes\index.js:36:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the registrations returned from the database query to the template as follows:

```
router.get('/registrations', (req, res) => {
    Registration.find()
        .then((registrations) => {
            res.render('index', { title: 'Listing registrations', 'registrations': registrations });
        })
        .catch(() => { res.send('Something went wrong'); });
});
```

Comment: hufft, thank you so much, now i can continue my code :)